# Django: add new column by function ( datetimefield to datefield )

Tags: python, sql, django, django-models

### Change datetimefield to datefield and put in in new column

> python ways are useless because i want to be able to use **order_by** and **distinct**
> i don't want to use sorted() and etc

my django model is something like this

```py
class Product(models.Model):
    price = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=False, default=0)
    discounted_price = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=False, default=0)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

And i want to be able to call **date()** function
and put it in another column and **order_by** it

```py
Product.objects.annotate(day=date.date()).order_by('-day').distinct('day')
```

Comment: Why can't you change the type of the date field to `date = models.DateField()`?

Comment: because i need datetimefield for other purposes but in this particular query i just need date part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of search i found my answer

```py
from django.db.models.functions import TruncDate

Product.objects.annotate(day=TruncDate('date')).order_by('-day').distinct('day')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do somthing like this

```
Product.objects.annotate(date__date=date.date()).order_by('-date').distinct('date')
```

check [doc.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#date) for more information

Comment: thank you for your reply it was helpful but that's not my question
i don't want to filter date i want to distinct by **distinct('date__date')**